# touchesBegan to dismiss view

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have a view in my ViewController that takes up half the screen from bottom to mid-screen. I'm using touchesBegan function to dismiss the view if tapped somewhere else than inside the view, everything works except that when I touch on the 10% of the top on the view, it dismisses when it should not because the touch is still inside the allowed view.

This is my code to present the vc:

```
            guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editvc") as? EditTodoViewController else {return}
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                present(vc, animated: true)
```

and this is my function inside that vc:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if touch != viewForVc {
        EditTodoViewController.textFromCellForTodo = ""
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the touch is not in the view rather than check different

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
    
    if (!viewForVc.bounds.contains(location)) {
        EditTodoViewController.textFromCellForTodo = ""
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

--- Edit----

If you want to change the frame programmatically before check contains check the code below

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        
        // get the frame of view + 10% height
        let viewFrame = CGRect(origin: viewForVc.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: viewForVc.frame.size.width, height: viewForVc.frame.size.height * 1.1))
        
        if (!viewFrame.contains(location)) {
            EditTodoViewController.textFromCellForTodo = ""
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried it now, still dismisses when the click is inside the top of that view. Any other ideas on how to solve it? Thanks for helping

Comment: @kevzeter you can save the frame into the variable then plus the 10% height. After that you can take that frame using .contains like above. I think the reason is because of the when you touch your finger is bigger so the location is incorrect some way.

Comment: Sounds like something that could work.
Do you mind showing an example of how I could do this? I haven't been writing Swift or code for too long

Comment: @kevzeter I've edited the answer above. Hope can help you

Comment: This worked just fine, thanks for all the help!

Comment: No problem. Check my answer as the correct answer is enough